# set slope to 1 in linear regression in r

Tags: r, regression

In R, lm(y~x) will get the linear regression in terms of y=a+bx, giving the estimates of both slope and intercept. Now I want to set the slope to 1, and do the regression, which means the form of the regression should be y=a+x (since b is forced to be one), and the estimate of intercept will be generated. How can I achieve that in R? And how can I compare the regression of the slope 1 with regression of the estimated slope b?

Comment: Questions solely about 'how to do ____ in R' are off topic here. However, note that if you look at the documentation [?lm](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lm.html), you will see there is an `offset` argument which will do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $b=1$ then,
$$y=a+x \rightarrow (y-x)=a$$
then $\hat a=mean(y-x)$

For comparing you can compare residuals.

maybe it is useful : http://stattrek.com/regression/slope-test.aspx?Tutorial=AP